# How do I get the first values in list of list as separate list?

Tags: python, list

How do I get the first values in a list of list as separate list??

For example:

```
A =  [ [[1,4.9], [2,90],[3,8]], [[2,34],[4,78],[9,10]], [[1,90],[3,100]] ]
```

the result should be as:

```
B = [ [1,2,3],[2,4,9],[1,3] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [99]: A =  [ [[1,4.9], [2,90],[3,8]], [[2,34],[4,78],[9,10]], [[1,90],[3,100]] ]

In [100]: [[item[0] for item in subl] for subl in A]
Out[100]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 9], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the question +1, but it might be more advanced than the OP is looking for. It might be better to break it down to a basic for loop then to use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
[map(None,*k)[0] for k in A]
[(1,2,3),(2,4,9),(1,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getFirstValues(A):
    B = list()
    for eachListofList in A:
        currentList= list()
        for eachList in eachListofList:
            currentList.append(eachList[0])
        B.append(currentList)
     return B
```

Comment: An explanation can be helpful.